# Why is str_replace not working correctly

Tags: php

In my directory I have a `list.csv` of the form:

```
RP2015, active
Hope, paused 
Process99, active
```

I'm writing a php script to allow a web user to switch the different lines from 'active' to 'paused' and back. Unfortunately I've hit a snag. My current code is live at: http://whitewaterwriters.com/Driver/index.php

and it looks like this

```
     <HTML>
   <Body>

   <?
   if ($_POST != null) {
           $target = $_POST ['sprint'];
           echo "<br>Target was:".$target;
           $replacement=str_replace('active','paused',$target);
           if (strpos($target,'paused') !== false) {
                 $replacement=str_replace('paused','active',$target);
          }       
          echo "<br>Replacement was:".$replacement."<br>";
          $filename = "list.csv";
         $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
          print "<br>contents was:".$contents;
          $new_contents = str_replace($target, $replacement, $contents);
          print "<br>contents became:".$new_contents;
          file_put_contents($filename, $new_contents);
  }       
  ?>      
<br><br>
  <?php
  $row = 1;
  if (($handle = fopen("list.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
              $num = count($data);
              $row++;
              echo '<form action="index.php" method=post>';
              echo $data[0] . $data[1];
              echo '<button type="submit" value="'. $data[0].", ".$data[1].'"     name="sprint">Pause</button></form><br>';
     }
      fclose($handle);
  }
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

For some reason the replace is not firing. The event is captured, the correct target and replace strings are (I think) generated, but the replace is NOT coming out. The output I get is:

```
Target was:RP2015, active
Replacement was:RP2015, paused

contents was:RP2015, active
contents became:RP2015, active

RP2015 active
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

EDIT:

The current list.csv is exactly:

```
RP2015, active
```

`

Comment: you can remove the `$fp = fopen($filename, 'r+');` and `fclose($fp);` you are not using them anywhere.

Comment: yeah, file_put_contents doesn't work with fopen! so you don't need that lines

Comment: can you share few rows from list.csv

Comment: Oooh thanks @AlexAndrei - that's useful to know.

Comment: @n01ze - I've made an edit - list.csv is literally 'RP2015, active' right now :)

Comment: Are you sure that your `$target` is *exactly* what is in the CSV? No extra spaces, etc?

Comment: By the way, `$_POST` is a superglobal and never `null`. You should use `array_key_exists` to check if your variable was POSTed.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - just now I copied and pasted the $target output on page into a temp file and diff'ed it with the csv - full match. :s

Comment: Thanks @BartFriederichs  - if nothing else I'm getting a good code review from this question :)

Comment: Can you `strpos($contents, $target)` to see it finds it at all? If not, the `$target` string isn't in `$contents` (and will not be replaced). In that case, there have to be differences. Note that they can be character set problems, stray unprintable characters, etc.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - ah-ha! Answer follows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I had forgotten is that html squashes consecutive spaces together which is why the $target looked like it was fine. Actually:

```
$data[0].", ".$data[1]
```

only needed to be

```
$data[0].",".$data[1]
```

Because there was a space left over from the csv parsing. I'll make the code a bit more robust to that in future.

For the interested - this helper function I wrote helped me locate the error:

```
    function toask($inStr){
 $arr1 = str_split($inStr);
    foreach ( $arr1 as $a){
      print ord($a)." ";
      }
      }
```

It converts a string to a sequence of ascii codes do you can make sure, for example, that quote characters are the ones you think they are...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-
    $fp = fopen($filename, "wb");
    $handle = fopen($filename, "wb");
    $replacement = str_replace("active", "paused", $fp);
    $numbytes = fwrite($handle, $replacement);
    fclose($handle);